Error copying a table from one db to another
I have are two tables: GP_HASTA_KABUL in one database and gelis in a different database in same SQL Server.
I need to copy from GP_HASTA_KABUL to gelis (and eventually more tables, as well). This is what I have so far, but it gives me a System.InvalidOperationException:
public static void veribagla(string source_table= "GP_HASTA_KABUL", string destination_table = "gelis")
{
    string sourceConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-FUHDPK9K\\HIZIR;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
    string destinationConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-FUHDPK9K\\HIZIR;Initial Catalog=ahmet;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
    using (SqlConnection sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceConnectionString))
    {

        sourceConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + source_table, sourceConnection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString))
        { 
            destinationConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destination_table;
                try
                {
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                    Console.WriteLine("Data transfer complete.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

How can I do this?

What the error is?

"SELECT * FROM " + source_table  looks suspicious. Seems you need extra quotation marks

The destination table needs to already exist, you need to have insert access and you probably need to be a server admin or else have the database ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permission.

If you're just copying tables in SQL Server you probably don't need any code. It's likely that you can do it with a single SQl statement. [dba.se] is the place to ask.

To start, remove the try/catch, so you can see which exact line of code throws the error. Then, share the exception message with us, and not just the exception type.

I successfully implemented this code on my SQL Server 2014. Just change the database connection and table names. It was on .Net Frameork 4.7.2.
But, When I was tried it with .Net 6 .0 it asked for namespace Microsoft.Data.SQLClient instead of System.Data.SQLClient.  Other issues are also there. If you want to use other than .net framework you have to make changes.

@AbuBenReaz SQL Server 2014 is fully end of life... it no longer gets any updates: not even critical security patches.  Time to upgrade.

If the tables really do have the same columns, you can do it in much less code and MUCH more efficiently like this:
public static void veribagla(string source_table= "GP_HASTA_KABUL", string destination_table = "gelis")
{
    string SQL = @$"
INSERT INTO ahmet..{destination_table}
SELECT * FROM TestDB..{source_table};
";

    string ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-FUHDPK9K\\HIZIR;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
    using var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cn);
    try 
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine($"Data transfer from {source_table} to {destination_table} complete.");
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

Bulk Copy is best for when the data is not already directly accessible to the destination server. This keeps the data entirely within the database server, rather than having to pull it down from the database into your app and then send it right back again.

If it were me, I'd also validate the input by checking Information_Schema or Sys.Tables to ensure valid inputs, and then use the information returned from the database rather than the argument provided to the method. Otherwise, you're crazy-vulnerable to injection issues:
public static void veribagla(string source_table= "GP_HASTA_KABUL", string destination_table = "gelis")
{
    string tableSQL = @"
select * from (
    select top 1 QUOTENAME(table_schema) as [schema], QUOTENAME(table_name) as [table], 0 ord
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where table_name = @SourceTable and TABLE_CATALOG = @SourceDB
    union
    select top 1 quotename(table_schema), quotename(table_name), 1
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where table_name = @DestTable and TABLE_CATALOG = @DestDB
) t
order by ord;
;"
    
    string source_schema = "dbo";
    string destination_schema = "dbo";

    string ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-FUHDPK9K\\HIZIR;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
    using var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(tableSQL, cn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SourceTable", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = source_table;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SourceDB", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = "TEST_DB";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DestTable", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = destination_table;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DestDB", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = "ahmet";

    try 
    {
        cn.Open();
        using var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var tables = new DataTable();
        tables.Load(rdr);
        rdr.Close();
 
        if (table.Rows.Count >= 2) 
        {
            source_schema = table.Rows[0]["schema"].ToString();
            source_table = tables.Rows[0]["table"].ToString();
            destination_schema = table.Rows[1]["schema"].ToString();
            destination_table = tables.Rows[1]["table"].ToString();


            string copySQL = @$"
INSERT INTO ahmet.{destination_schema}.{destination_table}
SELECT * FROM TestDB.{source_schema}.{source_table};
";

            cmd.CommandText = copySQL;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine($"Data transfer from {source_table} to {destination_table} complete.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table not found in database.");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

Normally I prefer sys.xxx objects instead of information schema, but in this case I found it much easer to also use the schema and catalog info by looking at the view.
